# Visual studio 2012 asp.net mvc 4 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

After creating the MVC 4 application in Visual studio 2012(OS - windows10).The application starts fine but unable to create RIGESTER or LOGIN page.
[image]
[Error on VS2012](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zK9z.png)

[image]
[Error on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AsdJ.png)

Note:
1)I restarted the system and try the latest update but non of the step worked.

Comment: Check connection string, application is not able to access Database for Membership.

Comment: And what does your database connection string look like?

Comment: "error connecting to the sql server"?